# date issues when exporting datagrid to excel

Tags: excel, datagrid

i have the following code to export he contents of my datagrid in excel format.It works but the problem is that n the column where the date is displayed instead of the date it displays "########".I have to manually format the column in order to display the date correctly.Is there any way to do that automatically when expoting?
Thank you in advance.

```
Public Sub export_auto_oraria()
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    'create object of excel
    ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    With ExcelSheet
        For i = 1 To Me.DataGridView3.RowCount
            .cells(i, 1) = Me.DataGridView3.Rows(i - 1).Cells("d_id").Value
            For j = 1 To DataGridView3.Columns.Count - 1
                .cells(i, j + 1) = DataGridView3.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
            Next
        Next
    End With

    ExcelApp.Visible = False

    ExcelSheet = Nothing



    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\book1.xlsx"
        ExcelBook.SaveAs(path)
        ExcelApp.Workbooks.Close()
        ExcelApp.Quit()

end sub   '? is this where it ends
```

Answer (score 0):

This addition to your data transfer should help.

```
With ExcelSheet
    For i = 1 To Me.DataGridView3.RowCount
        .cells(i, 1) = Me.DataGridView3.Rows(i - 1).Cells("d_id").Value
        For j = 1 To DataGridView3.Columns.Count - 1
            .cells(i, j + 1) = DataGridView3.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
        Next
    Next
    For j = 1 To DataGridView3.Columns.Count
        .columns(j).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next
End With
```

Comment: @DimitrisDimitri - please remember that `.AutoFit` does not solve problems like Excel using scientific notation for large numbers as the scientific notation is already assumed to be within the column width. Phone numbers without hyphens can easily be obfuscated this way and become useless.